# Trying to send a message to a specific channel from a different file , discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i splitted some code into another file and i get "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'"
as i read , its should be a error like "the channel dont exist" "the bot dont have permission"
but tahts wrong , i can send messages just fine from the main.py in the specific channel just not from the loging.py . here my code .

```
#bot.py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, time, timezone
import time
import loging
load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("$"), help_command=None)

@bot.command(name='test', help='this command will test')
async def test(ctx):
    await loging.comlog(ctx)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

```
#loging.py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, time, timezone
import time

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("$"), help_command=None)
timestamp = datetime.now()
timenow = str(timestamp.strftime(r"%x, %X"))

async def comlog(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    channelid = ctx.channel.id
    username = ctx.author
    usernameid = ctx.author.id
    logingchan = await bot.fetch_channel(983811124929630239)
    em = discord.Embed(title=f'${ctx.command}', description=f'{timenow}', color=0x00FF00)
    em.set_thumbnail(url=username.avatar_url)
    em.add_field(name="Channel:", value=f'{ctx.channel.mention} \n{channelid}', inline=True)
    em.add_field(name="User:", value=f'{username}\n{usernameid}', inline=True)
    print(f'{timenow}: $help: in "{channel}" by "{username}"')
    await logingchan.send(embed=em)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

for testing i replaced the cahnnel with "ctx" and this works just fine

```
Ignoring exception in command test:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Asuka\Desktop\PROJECT\Discord_Bot\bot.py", line 149, in test
    await loging.comlog(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Asuka\Desktop\PROJECT\Discord_Bot\loging.py", line 23, in comlog
    await logingchan.send(embed=em)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Asuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Asuka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

yea i know ppl say now , the cahnnel dont exist , the bot dont have premmision . false , why can i send in the exact same channel with my main.py but not with the loging.py . also , if i dont send in a specific channel , and send the embed in channel where the command got used , and i use the channel with the id , my bot can reply in the exact same channel.

Comment: Can you send the full error traceback? If you want to have nice-looking error messages that can be achieved by using `on_command_error`/`on_error`/`@command.error` or using try-except.

Comment: error traceback in edited version.

Comment: That means the logging channel is `None`, meaning that this channel ID either doesn't exist, isn't accessible from the bot, or isn't cached. You can try fetching the channel instead.

Comment: i guess the channel isnt cached , since if i change for test `await ctx.send(embed=em)` and i can send (aslong i use the command inside) just perfect .

if i use `logingchan = bot.fetch_channel(852506521237585933)` i get error 
`TypeError: coroutine.send() takes no keyword arguments`

and if i use `logingchan = await bot.fetch_channel(852506521237585933)` i get a error
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'`

Comment: `get_channel` will return `None` if the channel can not be found. Make sure that the channel id is correct and that your bot has permissions to access the channel.

Comment: as i said , in the main.py works the channel id just find , and if i send the msg in command cahnnel used , and i use the exact same channel for testing its works fine too.

Comment: You need to await the coroutine because “calling” it doesn’t execute it. If it can’t be fetched then you need to check if the channel is actually existent. Go to the channel and get its ID again, and verify the bot has permissions to see the channel.

Comment: the channel id is 100% right , my bot have all permissions , i can use the same embed in my bot.py and send in the channel id just fine , i start having the problem since i try to use the code in loging.py. i just tested rn , and i still can send in the channel from the bot.py .

Comment: `bot` doesn't exist in `logging.py`, you would probably need to put that in a class or add bot as one of the arguments.

Comment: very sorry i have it , i edited here my post again with all included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two separate bots in your two modules.

In the bot.py, you make a bot that you later run with the `run` method. This bot is fine, and it's connected to discord and can do a bunch of things.

However, you made a *second* bot in logging.py. This bot isn't actually doing anything and it was never started, so any attempts to get or fetch anything from discord will fail. What you need to do is to give the bot instance to the other module.

You can do this by either putting it into a class, or passing the bot as an argument, which I will show here:

```py
async def comlog(bot, ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    channelid = ctx.channel.id
    username = ctx.author
    usernameid = ctx.author.id
    logingchan = await bot.fetch_channel(983811124929630239)
    em = discord.Embed(title=f'${ctx.command}', description=f'{timenow}', color=0x00FF00)
    em.set_thumbnail(url=username.avatar_url)
    em.add_field(name="Channel:", value=f'{ctx.channel.mention} \n{channelid}', inline=True)
    em.add_field(name="User:", value=f'{username}\n{usernameid}', inline=True)
    print(f'{timenow}: $help: in "{channel}" by "{username}"')
    await logingchan.send(embed=em)
    await ctx.message.delete()

# Then pass in the bot when you call the function
@bot.command(name='test', help='this command will test')
async def test(ctx):
    await loging.comlog(bot, ctx)
```

Then you can just delete your second bot definition in logging.py.

---

If you want permission failure messages you need to use try/except:

```py
try:
    await logingchan.send(embed=em)
except discord.errors.Forbidden:
    # don't have permissions, do something here
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a bot variable in loging.py

If you want to split bot commands you should make cogs instead

Cogs are like command groups

This is how you do it:

```py
# main.py

from discord.ext import commands
from loging import my_commands_cog

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "idk!")

bot.add_cog(my_commands_cog)

# loging.py

from discord.ext import commands

class my_commands_cog(commands.Cog)

  @commands.command(name = "idk")
  async def idk(ctx, * , arg):
    # stuff
    print("idk")
```

Check it out here: [Cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html)

Comment: tyvm but i wanted to just export the lines of code , so they can be used from every command and give me a log of what happened , so far i see you exported the whole command , thats sadly not what iam looking for , idk if i can used it similar in the way i want to.

Comment: I try a different approach for my bot. I would make a function that takes some inputs and output an embed for me to send the channel I want. Is that what you want?

Comment: yea kinda like , i have 3 commands for now in main.py , and if they get used i want them all use the same code showed in loging.py